# SalesForce - Find list of all Campaigns

Tags: salesforce

How do I find the list of all of Campaigns via the REST API?
I did try something like the following , but I dont see its working

```
  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
  $response=$mySforceConnection->retrieve("IsActive, ParentId, Name, Type","Campaign");
```

Thanks

Comment: "not working" how? Describe the error, the symptoms, something.

Comment: well , I think I am using the wrong call for getting the list of campaigns. so i think the call to get list of campaigns using the following line   $response=$mySforceConnection->retrieve("IsActive, ParentId, Name, Type","Campaign");
 is not correct,  Any idea how can I receive the list of Campaign ?